# Python Key Error exception when navigating api requests

Tags: python

Everyone!

The API I'm using has a limit of 50 objects per request so I'm using their scroll api to get the next page, but when I navigate through the last page its X-Next-Page header parameter does not exist and it throws this error

> KeyError: 'x-next-page'

The code I'm using:

```
        while request.headers['X-Next-Page'] is not None:
            url = "https://api-2445582011268.apicast.io%s" % request.headers['X-Next-Page']
            request = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
            # break if api key hit usage limit
            if request.status_code == 403:
                print("API key reached its limit")
                break
```

So how do I check if request.headers has X-Next-Page properly? Thank you

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm just trying to learn

Comment: Some people may find this question somewhat, "dumb". If you checked the Python docs a little bit you may have found the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use dict.get() function

```
while request.headers.get('X-Next-Page') is not None:
    url = "https://api-2445582011268.apicast.io%s" % request.headers['X-Next-Page']
    request = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
    # break if api key hit usage limit
    if request.status_code == 403:
         print("API key reached its limit")
         break
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It may be useful to mention that `get` returns a default of `None` when its optional secondary arg is not supplied.